# Are there regulations about carrying cargo on passenger seats?

Tags: safety, regulations, weight-and-balance, cargo

We see that passenger aircraft have recently made cargo flights so that the supply chain does not decrease due to the Covid-19 crisis.

It is seen that the cargo boxes are loaded on the passenger seats by fastening them with a strap or rope.

https://twitter.com/AHoensbroech/status/1243095677485436928?s=09

Are there any regulatory restrictions (firefighting, smoke detection, aircraft weight&balance etc.) or guidance on carrying loads on the main deck of wide-body passenger aircrafts without removing the passenger seats (there will be no passengers on board)?

[image: cardboard boxes]

Comment: I removed the [pilots] tag because the question has nothing to do with it. Why did you add it again?

Comment: I want them to see that new concept and make the possible contribution. Would you stop editing my tags all the time?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what tags are for, see [the tagging help page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/tagging). Tagging [pilots] does not mean that pilots will be informed about this question or that they should answer it. It means that the question itself is about pilots, which this one isn't. Also, what do you mean by "all the time"? I edited once.

Comment: Thx for sharing the guide. I care about the answer to this question so i don’t want to leave more comments.